# Splitting rows of Nested Table OR Inner Table using iTextPDF

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

How do I split the rows of the inner table. Problem description according to the image.

1. Here, I have table named ***PARENT_TABLE*** that has cell that contains two tables named ***HEADER_TABLE*** and ***CONTENT_TABLE***
2. **CONTENT_TABLE** has a cell that contains **INNER_TABLE**. INNER_TABLE  contains the dynamic rows/content whose height will be changed according to content.

So, If I make this table using one page it's working perfectly. But incase if I need to split the table in different pages it shows the error like image_2. Please help me out. **As a result:** The table should look like in the image_1 even if the page split into two or more pages.

*Please checkout mentioned image to be more clear.*

image_1
[image]

Attempt to read from field 'float com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.maxY' on a null object reference

image_2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution. The issue occurs only in the case when trying to split the PDFPTable into two pages. I had used *tableCell.setRowspan(2)*, so when trying to split the table above issue occurs.

SOLVED IT: I just made an empty cell in place of using *tableCell.setRowspan(2)*.

```
private PdfPTable contentWithDateTitleAndDescription(String stringData1, String stringData2, String stringData3, String stringData4) throws IOException, BadElementException {

        float relativeWidth[] = {2, 7};
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(relativeWidth);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);

        PdfPCell cellA = new PdfPCell();
        cellA.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        // dateCell.setRowspan(2);
        cellA.setPaddingLeft(15);
        cellA.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellA.setPaddingTop(7);
        Paragraph dateParagraph = new Paragraph(stringData1);
        cellA.addElement(dateParagraph);

        PdfPCell emptyCellB = new PdfPCell();
        emptyCellB.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);


        PdfPCell cellC = new PdfPCell();
        cellC.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cellC.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        Paragraph titleParagraph = new Paragraph(stringData2 + " / " + stringData3);
        cellC.addElement(titleParagraph);


        PdfPCell cellD = new PdfPCell();
        cellD.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cellD.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        Paragraph descriptionParagraph = new Paragraph(stringData4);
        cellD.addElement(descriptionParagraph);
        cellD.setPaddingBottom(15);

        table.addCell(cellA);
        table.addCell(cellC);
        table.addCell(emptyCellB);
        table.addCell(cellD);
        return table;

    }
```